# OpenCart test site in subfolder has blank template dropdown

Tags: opencart

I copied my OpenCart 1.4.9 site into a subfolder to create a test site. I restored the original db to a new db.  I pointed the config.php files to the new locations and db.  They seem to be working but now when I go to Settings/Store the template field displayed a blank button with up/down arrows.  It should be displaying "default" and "modern store".

Any Ideas how to restore the template options?

Comment: Do you have the `theme` folders in `catalog/view/theme/` folder? Is everything ok with the frontend?

Comment: Yes. The theme folders are there.

Comment: Is everything ok with the frontend? or are you getting errors in frontend ?

Comment: This may be also in `.htaccess` - after moving to a subfolder, did You edit the `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /subfolder/` ?

Answer (score 0):

it's been a long time, I guess the issue is solved somehow, but I will post the solution so it can be helpful for someone else:

the problem is the 'config.php' file inside the 'admin' folder, check that the 'DIR_CATALOG' definition exists and it's a valid and correct path.